# Just chopped two USB cables,but one of them looks unusual

Tags: usb, soldering, wiring, wire, colour-coding

I just chopped two USB cables but one of them has three white cables and one grey. The other wire has normal colouring of:-Black, Green, White, Red

First wire:

- White
- White(has single orangestrand)
- White(has orange strand too)
- Grey

Could someone tell me what combination should is use to connect them to each other.
I am connecting microUSB to USB 2.0.

Comment: You can use an electrical meter or battery and LED to check which wire connects to which pin on the other end of the cable.

Comment: We don't know which cable is which. If you want to do this, then you need to figure out which is which. Even if the two cables had identical colored wires, it would still be wise to check if the colors match or are they arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

By using a multimeter and some common sense, we can:

- Ignore the colors.
- Check the expected pinout for the particular USB connector. Likely 1) +, 2) D+, 3) D-, 4) GND.
- Use a multimeter to tell which wire that happens to be connected to which pin, then connect them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange but probably the standard doesn't mandate the colours on the cable. However it mandates the cable specification.

The two power cables (usually black and red) are of bigger cross section, while the data cable is a twisted pair. A simple multimeter on ohm or continuity will find the correct pairing.

However if you simply hope to tie two cable together most probably you'll violate the transmission line specifications and you'll have… issues with data. If it's only a cable for supply provisioning (i.e. a charging cable) maybe you'll get it to work fine.

Comment: The USB standard really does mandate the color of the cable! https://web.archive.org/web/20140519092924/http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/documents_archive/usb_30_spec_070113.zip -> USB3_r1.0_06_06_2011.pdf -> Section 5.4.2

Comment: Good to know. I wrote *maybe* because I was too lazy to check. That's really a china quality cable